# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when removing object from NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a NSMutableDictionary as the datasource for my UITableView. I am trying to implement the delete mode and having an issue.

I am logging the key I am trying to remove as well as the object that it corresponds to as this issue seems like it might be related to my trying to access unallocated memory or something. Here is my implementation of tableView:commitEditionStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source.
        NSArray * keys = [userList allKeys];
        NSNumber *keyToRemove = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"Key to remove: %@",keyToRemove);
        NSLog(@"Object at key: %@",[userList objectForKey:keyToRemove]);
           [userList removeObjectForKey:keyToRemove];   
              [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [keys release];
        [keyToRemove release];

    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }   
}
```

This method runs and then I get the error. The two NSLog statements output the correct key and it's corresponding value.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't own `keys` or `keysToRemove`, so you should not be releasing them. I strongly suggest reading up on the [Cocoa memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/).

Comment: oops.. they are never allocated.. I've read it.. just being dumb. Thanks!

Comment: They ARE being allocated, but not by you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
[keys release];
[keyToRemove release];
```

You are releasing keys and keyToRemove, even though you never allocated it, retained it, or copied it, so it's reference count is decreasing more than it should.

As a general rule, you should only release an object if you called alloc, **retain** (not init, sorry) or copy on it, I recommend you read on reference counting here: [Practical Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html)

Comment: That's not quite the correct list of methods that confer ownership. It's slightly complicated (e.g. it's any method beginning in `alloc…`) and it's best to just refer to the memory management rules, but it's basically NARC — `new`, `alloc`, `retain` and `copy`.

Comment: Indeed, it was a typo (the list is actually correct on the first paragraph :/).